# Cannot format as code

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

The "format as code" button is not working properly when I attempt to format the stack trace in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17128445/2157772) as code. Whenever I try to format it, nothing happens. What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have an empty line between your description and the text you want formatted as code. Otherwise, it assumes that it's all just part of a big paragraph and all the extra white-space just gets collapsed.